# Jquery Cycle plugin and scrollVert

Tags: jquery, cycle

Anybody know the easiest way to create a scrolVert effect with the Cycle plugin which scrolls up to display the next item rather than scrolling down as is default?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "rev" option :

```
rev: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fx: 'scrollUp'
```

in cycles options should do the trick.